# Angular1: module with component: how to call controller method from the template returning data

Tags: angularjs

I have a module with a component that is a simple calculator.

How can I call from the copmnent template the controller methods?

How can I pass from the controller methods the result back to the component template?

**HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="controllersWithMethods">
<head>
    <script src="app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="methods/methods.module.js"></script>
    <script src="methods/methods.component.js"></script>
</head>
<body>    
   <methods></methods>
</body></html>
```

**App.module.js:**

```
angular.module( 'methods', []);
```

**methods.template.js:**

```
<input type="number" ng-model="value1" />
<input type="number" ng-model="value2" />     
<button ng-click="add()"> + </button>
<button ng-click="multiply()"> x </button>   
<hr>
<p>
Value 1 = {{value1}}</br>
Value 2 = {{value2}}</br>
The result is: {{result}}
</p>
```

**methods.component.js:**

```
angular.
  module('methods').
  component('methods', {
    templateUrl: 'methods/methods.template.html',
    controller: function() {
      this.value1 = 0;
      this.value2 = 0;
      this.result = 0;
      this.add = function () { 
          this.result = this.value1 + this.value2;
      }
      this.multiply = function () { 
         this.result = this.value1  * this.value2;
      }
  }
});
```

What I see is that the methods are not called. The value1 and value2 are visible, the result not.

Of course, I can call from the app's outer component the controller and work with $scope. I read that working with components is a more decent way of setting up the software.

Comment: In your component's definition you need to add bindings to for the variables and functions you want to use [as shown in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

Comment: I understand. In THIS situation the template (method call and variables) is within the SAME component. Aren't these component 'local' variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved.**

Without bindings. The bindings are not necessary because the variables are within the same component. See the code below, the other 2 files were not changed.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="number" ng-model="$ctrl.value1" />
<input type="number" ng-model="$ctrl.value2" />
<button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.add()"> + </button>
<button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.multiply()"> x </button>
<hr>
<p>
Het resultaat is: {{$ctrl.result2}}
</p>
```

**Angular:**

```
angular.
  module('methods').
  component('methods', {
    templateUrl: 'methods/methods.template.html',
    controller: function() {
      function add() { 
        this.result2 = this.value1 + this.value2;
      }
      function multiply() { 
        this.result2 = this.value1  * this.value2;
      }
      this.add = add;
      this.multiply = multiply;
   } 
});
```